# How to pull results from query outside the main loop

Tags: soql

Can someone suggest correction to my below code. Unable to get FederationId inside the CaseRecord as I have to query it outside the main loop

```
list<id> userIds = new list<Id>();
list<string> fedId = new list<string>();
list<case> caseList = [SELECT id, ownerId, owner.name, accountId, owner.type from case WHERE owner.type = 'user' LIMIT 1];
for(case c : caseList){
    system.debug('case record start');
    system.debug(c.id);
    system.debug(c.ownerId);
    userIds.add(c.ownerId);
    system.debug(c.owner.name);
    system.debug(c.owner.type);
    system.debug('FederationId:'+fedId);
    system.debug('case record End');    
}

for(user u : [SELECT Id, federationIdentifier from User WHERE Id IN : userIds]){
    fedId.add(u.FederationIdentifier);
}
```

Comment: So What I understood. you want to get some user's(say owner ID) federation ID inside for loop for case record ? ...rt ? .. ..you can use maps for same purpose  having user id and federation ID  as key & value pair.  Or am I missing something in understanding here ?

Comment: I noted in some forums that federationIdentifier on user cannot be queried because when I am using email, I am able to get the output. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not entirely clear what your use case is here, so there's a couple of different possible answers to your question. Let me tell you what I see and you can decide how to use the information. Your initial query which has a limit 1 on it is declared as a list, when in fact it only returns 1 record, so can be declared as a single case as below:

```
case c = [SELECT id, ownerId, owner.name, accountId, owner.type from case WHERE owner.type = 'user' LIMIT 1];
```

Once you do this, you no longer need the `for(case c : caseList)` loop you've declared below it. You can just use the statements as they are with the addition of the following query immediately after the above revised query:

```
user u = [SELECT Id, federationIdentifier from User WHERE Id = : c.OwnerId];
```

I don't have an org available that's configured for OAuth, so I can't test this, but you should be able to combine your two queries using a subquery that would look something like below:

```
case c = [SELECT id, ownerId, owner.name, accountId, owner.type, (SELECT Id, federationIdentifier from Users WHERE Id = : OwnerId) from case WHERE owner.type = 'user' LIMIT 1];
```

Again, you'll want to check the syntax of the nested query and test it out. I'm not totally confident of the WHERE clause in it since I've not tested it and don't normally need a WHERE clause in my nested queries. You may not need a WHERE clause at all since only the OwnerId is being referenced in the query. That's part of why you'll need to test it to see.

The initial query selects a random case, which is the reason I don't understand the use context for your code. One couldn't populate a list with this type of statement without being more specific criteria and increasing the LIMIT on records being returned since it could easily wind up being a non-selective query. Assuming you did that, you could immediately obtain the Id's of the Users and as per the comments, map them to the case Id using code like below:

```
for(case c : caseList){
   userIds.add(c.OwnerId);
{

map<Id,user> usrMap = new map<Id,user>([SELECT Id, federationIdentifier from User WHERE Id IN : userIds]);

map<Id,Id>cId2fId = new map<Id,Id>();
for(case c : caseList){
   if(usrMap.contains(c.OwnerId)){
      cId2fId.put(c.Id,usrMap.get(c.OwnerId).federationIdentifier);
   {
{
```

You now have a map of case Id to federation Id. Since you already know the ownerId, I thought it best to map it against the case Id. However, should the owner of the case change, this will need to be updated, so any workflow you have would need to take this into account. Again, I don't know your use case or purpose to advise further.

Comment: Thanks crmprogdev. This a very detailed explanation. Thanks for your time. This is really helpful.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Your question is ideally suited to the StackExchange model for reusability, which is why I went into this level of detail. I prefer to "teach others to fish." This answer covered much about queries, including returning lists, single records, making them selective, sub-queries and more. It also covered use of maps plus aspects of why we approach coding the way we do with Apex in Salesforce. Glad you found it helpful.